# Kubuntu 13.10 - backintime-kde do not start

Tags: kubuntu, backup, kde

I have a Kubuntu 13.10 64bit fresh install.

I installed backintime and backintime-kde4

When I launch backintime-kde4 it crashes saying:

```
mirto@msb03:~/script$ backintime-kde4

Back In Time
Version: 1.0.10

Back In Time comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `backintime-kde4 --license' for details.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/backintime/kde4/app.py", line 1136, in <module>
    main_window = MainWindow( cfg, app_instance, kapp, kaboutdata )
  File "/usr/share/backintime/kde4/app.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.list_files_view_model.removeColumns( 3, 2 )
TypeError: KDirModel.removeColumns() is a private method
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

As Mirto [already pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/370326/37580) this was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/backintime/+bug/1232694) in versions `<= 1.0.26`

To fix this manually you can comment out (by putting `#` at the start of it) the line `self.list_files_view_model.removeColumns( 3, 2 )` in `/usr/share/backintime/kde4/app.py`

You could do this (for example) by running

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/\(self.list_files_view_model.removeColumns( 3, 2 )\)/#\1/g' /usr/share/backintime/kde4/app.py
```

(This also makes a local backup of the original file)

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-Dev Team</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is known: launchpad Bug #1232694